# Append CellType Index Out Of Range Error Swift

Tags: swift, append, indexoutofboundsexception, nsindexpath

After appending a new cellType my locationTableViewCell is giving an error at let place = places[indexPath.row] while entering text inside the text field search bar.

```
private func locationTableViewCell(indexPath: IndexPath) -> PostSelectLocationTableViewCell {
    let locationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as PostSelectLocationTableViewCell
    let place = places[indexPath.row]
    locationCell.configure(model: place)
    return locationCell
}

locationInteractor.didPlacesLoaded = { [weak self] places in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.places = places
            if self?.places.isEmpty == true {
                self?.cellTypes = [.empty]
            } else {
                self?.cellTypes += Array(repeating: .location, count: self?.places.count ?? 0)
            }
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return cellTypes.count
}
```

before appending .currentLocation everything was peachy. But now when I enter a text to search between locations, it crashes with Index Out Of Range error. I have tried to let place = places[indexPath.row + 1] and let place = places[indexPath.row - 1] but it was ineffective.

```
locationInteractor.didCurrrentPlaceLoaded = { [weak self] currentPlace in
        self?.currentLocation = currentPlace
        self?.cellTypes.append(.currentLocation)
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my previous numberOfRowsInSection was as below.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellTypes.count
}
```

so this was causing me index out-of-range error.

After changing numberOfRowsInSection as below for each specific celltype my error is gone.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //  sponsored by Serhat Sezen
        if !places.isEmpty {
            return places.count
        } else {
            return cellTypes.count
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?